# trim the time out of the range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use PostgreSQL, and I'd love to trim the date if it's out of the range.

First thing I'd love to filter the records out of the range.
It's not difficult with query below. (Filter from 2017/3/1 ~ 2017/3/31)

```
select * from subscriptions where current_period_start_at <= date '2017/03/01' AND current_period_end_at >= date '2017/03/31'
```

However I'd love to cut off the date if it's out of the range(`2017-03-1 ~ 2017-03-31`).
current_period_start_at: `2017/02/25` => `2017/03/01`
current_period_end_at: `2017/04/02` => `2017/03/31`

Here is some example.

[image]

```
target　2016/08/05 ～ 2016/09/15　
range①　　2016/07/01 ～ 2016/08/31 => 2016/08/05 ～ 2016/08/31
range②　　2016/08/10 ～ 2016/09/20 => 2016/08/10 ～ 2016/09/15
range③　　2016/09/15 ～ 2016/10/10 => x out of the scope
range④　　2016/08/01 ～ 2016/09/30 => 2016/08/05 ～ 2016/09/15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `least()` function to get the lower of the values:

```
select  greatest(current_period_start_at, date '2016-08-05') as range_start, 
        least(current_period_end_at, date '2016-09-15') as range_end
from subscriptions
where (current_period_start_at,current_period_end_at) 
         overlaps (date '2016-08-05', date '2016-09-15');
```

If you don't want to repeat the date value, you can use a common table expression:

```
with range (r_start, r_end) as (
  values (date '2016-08-05', date '2016-09-15')
)
select greatest(current_period_start_at, r_start) as range_start,
       least(current_period_end_at, r_end) as range_end
from subscriptions, range
where (current_period_start_at,current_period_end_at) 
      overlaps (r_start, r_end);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I'd love to filter records between '2017-03-01', date '2017-03-31' of current periods and then, trim those dates if they are out of range.

Comment: oh sorry for my explanation. Trimming means if the target range is 2016/08/05 ～ 2016/09/15, and A(2016/07/01 ～ 2016/08/31 is in the range. But i'd love to cutoff the date out of range. In this case,  2016/07/01 should be 2016/08/05.

Comment: Thanks! also I could do trim current_period_start_at with the `least()`?

Comment: @Tosh: you probably want `greatest()` for the start of the range

Comment: Thanks! that's true!

Answer (score 3):

You should try daterange datatype.

```
SELECT daterange('2017-01-01'::date, '2017-03-01'::date) * daterange('2017-02-15'::date, '2017-05-01'::date);
```

returns

```
[2017-02-15,2017-03-01)
```

Comment: I knew it would be possible with date ranges ;)